# Hibernate inheritance update problem when generate HT table

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hbm

I have a problem about Hibernate 4.3.11 , I have two pojos : X and Y that Y extends X ,  Actually Y is a subjoin class in X.hbm . When i excute this update on Y pojo , All of the Y records have updated ,but I want to update Y where id is 123

This my HQL :

```
string hql = " update Y set Y.name = :name where e.id = :id "  
Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);  
query.setParameter("name",name);  
query.setParameter("id",123);  
query.executeUpdate();
```

When it excutes query it generates this SQL command :

```
update Y set Y.name = ? where (X_Id) IN(select X_Id from HT_Y)
```

Moreover I don't want to use createSQLQuery(...) , Do you have any solution to help me?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this query work?

```
String hql = "update Y set Y.name = :name where Y.id = :id"
```

Also, instead of `createQuery`, `CriteriaBuilder` can be used

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Y> criteria = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Y.class);
Root<Y> root = criteria.from(Y.class);
criteria.set(root.get("name"), name);
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), 123));
session.createQuery(criteria).executeUpdate();
```